# What are the internal limits to WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, networking, performance

WCF has lots of limits imposed on it to protect against DoS attacks and other developer brainlessness. What are these limits? And how can they be overriden?

Specifically, if I was to try to send a large number of messages in a short period of time to a variety of different clients, what are the internal WCF limits they may cause messages to be sent slowly.

PS: this question is a much shorter version of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371218/sending-wcf-messages-being-delayed-under-load) that did not get much attention.

**EDIT**
I have answered the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371218/sending-wcf-messages-being-delayed-under-load). The issue being my async calls were being turned into synchronous ones.

Comment: Looking at your previous question, I think you may be jumping to conclusions. Simplify this down to a trivial example and see if the behavior reproduces. _Then_ investigate limits. You're assuming that the behavior you're seeing is a matter of limits, and it may not be.

Comment: Completely agree, however my company isn't going to be happy about time spent producing a trivial / deterministic version. Tweaking config options is much simpler! I suspect I'll be enabling tracing soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many variables that could be involved that I find this question too general to answer. Some things you might want to check out are:

- [ServiceThrottlingBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.aspx) which allows you to limit the number of concurrent calls, instances and sessions
- [The service behaviour MaxObjectsInGraph property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx)
- [The MS patterns and practices WCF security Q&A](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949043.aspx)

But since security is a pretty complex topic and important to get right (it is only as strong as the weakest link) and WCF has so many different options, configuration properties etc... it would be smart to get some books and really get aquinted with the intracies.

I can personally recommend [Programming WCF 2nd edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-WCF-Services-Juval-Lowy/dp/0596521308/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252279644&sr=8-1) and [Learning WCF: A hands-on guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-WCF-Hands-Michele-Bustamante/dp/0596101627/ref=pd_sim_b_1)

---

After reading your previous question I also suggest you give tracing a try. WCF logs quite a bit about whats going on internally and when certain limits are hit. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx for more information about how to configure it. Pay special attention to the part about how XmlWriterTraceListener isn't thread-safe and might block execution flow and this severly impact performance (not something you want when debugging  performance)  and how to overcome this.

Lastly I think John Saunders his suggestion is very valid and if you do start with a trivial example and do not encounter this problem then I suggest you re-add your current functionality in small increments (or in a binary sort type of fashion) to see what it is that is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the (deliberately) vague question. I'm making sure I've reviewed all config options first. I suspect I'll be enabling tracing pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one I got stumped with and spent hours and hours to figure out. When you have IIS as web server, there is ASP.net setting which limits the max request size. So, the wcf service will not be able to ACCEPT a request over that size. In web.config, you'd need to add/change below setting (32 megs by default) -

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32767"/>
</system.web>
```

Of course, you've to be cognizant of possible DOS issues while increasing this limit.